# c, windows, printf()/scanf() и DWORD

Tags: c, printf, scanf

Какой спецификатор формата *правильно* использовать для печати/считывания значения названного типа?

На моей системе **DWORD** - это **unsigned long**. Но ведь может быть и иначе.

Для **size_t** есть "%Iu" в **Windows** и "%Zu" в **Linux**.

А для **DWORD**?

Comment: `%lu` - означает `unsigned long`, и размер size_t и DWORD в Windows совпадает (часто совпадает), поэтому создалось впечатление что для win `%lu`.

Comment: У меня там написана не ЭЛЬ, а И.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы в своем коде хотите абстрагироваться от конкретного типа, скрывающегося за `DWORD`, то вам придется завести промежуточный макрос-спецификатор самостоятельно, по аналогии с тем, как это сделано в стандартной библиотеке для типов вроде `uint64_t` (см. `PRIu64` в `<inttypes.h>`).

Например, если сейчас у вас `DWORD` - это `unsigned long`, то

```
#define DWORD_FMT "lu"

...
DWORD dw = 0;
scanf("%" DWORD_FMT, &dw);
printf("%" DWORD_FMT "\n", dw);
```

Поддерживать актуальность этого макроса вам тоже надо будет своими силами: если где-то когда-то тип, скрывающийся за `DWORD`, поменяется, то вы соответствующим образом поменяете макрос.

Если вы обратили внимание, в стандартной библиотеке для типов вроде `uint64_t` макросы заведены отдельно для `printf` и `scanf`, т.е. есть `PRIu64` и `SCNu64`. Можете тоже так поступить, хотя, наверное, в вашем случае большого смысла в этом нет.

---

> Для size_t есть "%Iu" в Windows и "%Zu" в Linux.

Префикс ширины для `size_t` - это `z` везде, и "и в Windows, и в Linux", т.е. везде именно `%zu`. Откуда и зачем вы взяли эти ваши странные варианты, да еще и разные - не ясно.

Comment: @Fat-Zer Да, точно. Спасибо. Исправил.

Comment: %Zu для Windows до недавнего времени работало только с компиляторами на основе GCC - например с MinGW. Возможно, в Clang тоже так можно было. Правильный спецификатор формата для вывода size_t в Windows - это %Iu. В последних версиях VS, кажется, позволили использовать %Zu, но это лишь в последних версиях.

Comment: @Максим: Во-первых, к ОС это не имеет никакого отношения вообще даже отдаленно, а определяется только реализацией. Во-вторых, нет никакого `%Zu`. Спецификатор ширины для `size_t` в стандартной библиотеке - `z`. Поэтому `%zu`, а не `%Zu`. В-третьих, поддержка `%zu` в реализации стандартной библиотеки MSVC появилась, конечно, не сразу аж в 1999 году, но все равно уже довольно давно. Где-то в 2010-2013.

Answer (score -1):

Используйте потоки cin и cout и не надо будет беспокоится о форматах. Страуструп не зря потоки придумал, как раз для этого случая.

Comment: В C нет cin/cout.

Comment: @Максим [В C нет cin/cout.] Это так принципиально? Сейчас уже почитай на всех платформах, где есть С есть и С++. К тому же у Вас в тегах и С++ стоит.